# Adding ng-model to Select multiple causes Options not to display in IE

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-tabset

This is so strange...I have a multiple select list.  If I add ng-model to the select. the option values display as below:

[image]

If I remove ng-model, the CompanyName shows correctly.

Here is my HTML:

```
 <tab heading="Contractors">
                        <div class="panel panel-default">
                            <div class="panel-body">

                                    <table style="width:100%">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                @Html.Label("Enter Name, FID, or SSQID")<br />
                                                <input type="text" style="width:200px"/>
                                            </td>
                                            <td rowspan="2">
                                                <select multiple ng-multiple="true" ng-model="selectedContractors">
                                                    <option ng-repeat="c in contractors" value="{{c.CompanyID}}">{{c.CompanyName}}</option>
                                                </select>
                                            </td>
                                            <td rowspan="2" style="align-content:center" ng-show="viewContractors">
                                                <i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right" style="cursor:pointer" ng-click="addContractor()"></i><br /><br />
                                                <i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-left" style="cursor:pointer"></i>
                                            </td>
                                            <td></td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="submitSearch(search)">Search</button>

                                            </td>
                                            <td></td>
                                            <td style="align-content:center"></td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </tab>
                </tabset>
```

Here is my controller code:

```
$scope.submitSearch = function (cs) {
    var id = $scope.businessUnitID;

operatorService.getsearch(cs, id)
.success(function (data) {
    $scope.contractors = data.SearchResults;
    $scope.viewContractors = true;

});
```

};

What is most perplexing is that I use the select multiple list EXACTLY the same way in another project but in that project the option values show correctly with ng-model.  I just can't make sense of this.

Since first posting this question, I have discovered that the issue seems to be caused by placing select on Angular ui-tabs, but it still only happens in IE.  If I move the select from the tab and just place it somewhere on the page, it works as aspected, but hence, I need it on the tabs.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated!

Comment: do you see any errors in browser console?

Comment: no errors in console.  This seems to only be an issue in IE as it displays correctly in Chrome; however, most of the users will be using IE.  Any ideas?

Comment: can you provide sample plunkr?

Comment: Okay, well the whole thing just got weirder!  It works in plunker, but not in project.  Here is plunker:  http://plnkr.co/edit/NqVECY7YTlbKrdz7oYXZ?p=preview

Comment: so, seems something wrong not with select, but with code around

Comment: usually you can see something like `{{c.CompanyName}}` in rendered code when error in angular parsing

Comment: okay, thanks.  I'm looking at the other code on the page.  It is still strange that it would only not work in IE and there's not much code on the rest of the page.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94850/discussion-between-grundy-and-rani-radcliff).

Comment: your plunker is empty.  also, you're not including any of the Angular UI Bootstrap libraries.  Finally, you're including Angular 1.2.x which is fine for UI-Grid, but not for Angular UI Bootstrap.  Angular UI Bootstrap 0.13.x and higher requires Angular 1.3+.