# Select Multiple does not work in IE when used with Angular-ui-Tabs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui-tabset

It took ALL day to get to the root of this problem.  This is related to question"[Adding ng-model to Select multiple causes Options not to display in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33655931/adding-ng-model-to-select-multiple-causes-options-not-to-display-in-ie)"  If I put ng-model on a select multiple on an Angular-uib-tab, the option list does not display correctly in IE (it works in Chrome).  Here is what I get in IE:

[image]

Here is my HTML:

```
<div ng-app="myModule" ng-controller="OperatorCtrl">

    <uib-tabset>
        <uib-tab>
            <select multiple ng-multiple="true" ng-model="selectedContractors">
                <option ng-repeat="c in contractors" value="{{c.CompanyID}}">{{c.CompanyName}}</option>
            </select>
        </uib-tab>
    </uib-tabset>
 <div>
     <select multiple ng-multiple="true" ng-model="selectedContractors">
         <option ng-repeat="c in contractors" value="{{c.CompanyID}}">{{c.CompanyName}}</option>
     </select>
 </div> 
</div>
```

It is the exact same "select multiple"  The one in between the uib-tab tags does not display properly, yet the one outside of the tags displays as expected.

I downloaded the latest version of the directives thinking that this issue may have possibly been fixed in the most recent version, but there was no change with my issue.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated!

If anyone has ANY knowledge regarding this issues, PLEASE help.

Answer (score 0):

you should use the "." in ng-model.

```
 <select multiple ng-multiple="true" ng-model="selected.contractors">
       <option ng-repeat="c in contractors" value="{{c.CompanyID}}">{{c.CompanyName}}</option>
 </select>
```

Comment: The problem come because I was using a custom directive with preventdefault()